# Java Hibernate Criteria returning only one entity fields

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, projection

i have a simple `Criteria` which is used by get the school of a student which i have the ID i need only the school not the student i have a simple coding like

```
public School loadSchool(Integer studentID) 
{        
    final Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    final Criteria like = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
    .add(idEq(studentID))
    .setFetchMode("School",FetchMode.JOIN); 
    final School retValue = ((Student)like.uniqueResult()).getSchool();
    session.close();
    return retValue;
}
```

as you can see i retrieve the `Student and the School` as well i need only the `School` my question are

1). there is a way other than `setProjections()` that i could extract[retrieve from the DB] only the `School fields` not the `Student fields` because are to many fields and is a kind annoying listing all the fields in `setProjection` and affects performance something like

`setProjectionOnlyPropertiesForClass(School.class)`.

2). there is any workaround.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're querying Student objects instead of School objects! The corresponding HQL query is:

```
select student
from Student student join student.school
where student.id=:studentId
```

Instead, you should query for School objects:

```
select school
from School school, Student student
where student.school = school and student.id=:studentId
```

(Maybe you should use HQL instead of criteria queries for that - they are simpler to write and understand).